# How to remove or disable the "Tabulator Selector" in Java on Windows OS?

Tags: java, windows

So my Java GUI always shows the current selected JButton by displaying a white rectangle around it. By hitting Tab or Shift + Tab the selection goes to the next/previous element.

Here is my custom decoration Panel(as an example). Is there a possiblity to hide this white frame?

By the way it has no function, if I press enter key nothing happens...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Method [setFocusPainted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted-boolean-) in class `javax.swing.AbstractButton`

Comment: Wow that was easy, thank you :)